Nextjs UseEffect is not working, i have tried many ways but it still isnt working
"use client";
import ServiceSection from "@/components/service-detail/ServiceSection";
import { sendRequest } from "@/utils/api";
import ListingDetail from "@/components/service-detail/ListingDetail";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function ServiceDetail({params}) {
  const [service, setService] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(serviceId)
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const resService = await sendRequest({
          method: "GET",
          url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/services/${params.serviceId}`,
        });

        setService(resService.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching service data:", error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [service, params.serviceId]);

  return (
    <>
      <ServiceSection service={service} />
      <ListingDetail service={service} />
    </>
  );
}


Why is useEffect not working? I've tried changing the dependency array in every possible way, but it's still not functioning. Can someone please help me?
